# How to use std::for_each on a range of boost::function objects?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-bind, boost-function

```
class User    
{    
public:

    User(){}    
    virtual ~User(){}
    void Test( int in )    
    {    
    }    
}    

User user;

vector< boost::function< void() > > functions;

functions.push_back( boost::bind( &User::Test, &user, 2 ) );

functions.push_back( boost::bind( &User::Test, &user, 4 ) );

for_each( functions.begin(), functions.end() , /* What goes here? */ );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
for_each( functions.begin(), functions.end(), mem_fn( &function< void() >::operator() ) );
```

Where `mem_fn` is either `std::tr1::mem_fn` or `boost::mem_fn`.